# How do I reapply filter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using TableSorter Version 2.28.1.   The first column of the table is a checkbox.  What I want to do is to use the filter to filter then rows, then have a link to check all checkboxes.  I have this working, but when it comes back the filter is gone and all rows are shown.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to re-apply the filter?

It should be noted that I have a masterpage and the table is built using the GRIDVIEW control.

```
            $("#<% =gvContractors.ClientID %>").tablesorter({
            showProcessing: true,
            sortList: [[1, 0]],
            headers: { 0: { sorter: false, filter: false} },
            widgets: ["zebra", "filter"],
            widgetOptions: {
                filter_liveSearch: true,
                filter_columnFilters: true,
                filter_childRows: true,
                filter_saveFilters: true
            }
        })
```

Here is my function to select all the checkboxes that are visible.

```
        function selectAllCheckboxes() {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#<% =gvContractors.ClientID %>').find("tr:visible").find('input').each(function () {
                $(this).closest('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', 'checked')
            });
        });
```

Comment: The `filter_saveFilters` option requires the [`widget-storage.js`](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/widgets/widget-storage.js) file to be loaded. Please make sure that is the case.

Comment: Thank you Mottie, That did the trick.